# extremely slow program from using AVX instructions

Tags: sse, simd, icc, avx, floating-point-exceptions

I'm trying to write a geometric mean sqrt(a * b) using AVX intrinsics, but it runs slower than molasses!

```c
int main()
{
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i)
  {
    __m128i v8n_a = _mm_set1_epi16((++count) % 16),
            v8n_b = _mm_set1_epi16((++count) % 16);
    __m128i v8n_0 = _mm_set1_epi16(0);
    __m256i temp1, temp2;
    __m256 v8f_a = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(temp1 = _mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(v8n_a, v8n_0)), _mm_unpackhi_epi16(v8n_a, v8n_0), 1)),
    v8f_b = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(temp2 = _mm256_insertf128_si256(_mm256_castsi128_si256(_mm_unpacklo_epi16(v8n_b, v8n_0)), _mm_unpackhi_epi16(v8n_b, v8n_0), 1));
    __m256i v8n_meanInt32 = _mm256_cvtps_epi32(_mm256_sqrt_ps(_mm256_mul_ps(v8f_a, v8f_b)));
    __m128i v4n_meanLo = _mm256_castsi256_si128(v8n_meanInt32),
       v4n_meanHi = _mm256_extractf128_si256(v8n_meanInt32, 1);
    g_data[i % 8] = v4n_meanLo;
    g_data[(i + 1) % 8] = v4n_meanHi;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The key to this mystery is that I'm using Intel ICC 11 and it's only slow when compiling with icc -O3 sqrt.cpp. If I compile with icc -O3 -xavx sqrt.cpp, then it runs 10x faster.

But it's not obvious if there's emulation happening because I used performance counters and the number of instructions executed for both versions is roughly 4G:

```
 Performance counter stats for 'a.out':

  16867.119538 task-clock                #    0.999 CPUs utilized
            37 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec
             8 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec
           281 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec
35,463,758,996 cycles                    #    2.103 GHz
23,690,669,417 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   66.80% frontend cycles idle
20,846,452,415 stalled-cycles-backend    #   58.78% backend  cycles idle
 4,023,012,964 instructions              #    0.11  insns per cycle
                                         #    5.89  stalled cycles per insn
   304,385,109 branches                  #   18.046 M/sec
        42,636 branch-misses             #    0.01% of all branches

  16.891160582 seconds time elapsed
```

-----------------------------------with -xavx----------------------------------------

```
 Performance counter stats for 'a.out':

   1288.423505 task-clock                #    0.996 CPUs utilized
             3 context-switches          #    0.000 M/sec
             2 CPU-migrations            #    0.000 M/sec
           279 page-faults               #    0.000 M/sec
 2,708,906,702 cycles                    #    2.102 GHz
 1,608,134,568 stalled-cycles-frontend   #   59.36% frontend cycles idle
   798,177,722 stalled-cycles-backend    #   29.46% backend  cycles idle
 3,803,270,546 instructions              #    1.40  insns per cycle
                                         #    0.42  stalled cycles per insn
   300,601,809 branches                  #  233.310 M/sec
        15,167 branch-misses             #    0.01% of all branches

   1.293986790 seconds time elapsed
```

Is there some kind of processor internal emulation going on? I know for denormal numbers, adds end up being 64 times slower than normal.

Comment: Which processor do you test on?

Comment: Xeon E2658   (Sandy Bridge)

Comment: It looks like you have a problem with AVX-SSE transitions

Comment: OK, great observation. I've confirmed with performance counters:     perf stat -e r10c1,r20c1 a.out

 Performance counter stats for 'a.out':

       200,000,003 r10c1
       200,001,376 r20c1

      16.883746025 seconds time elapsed                                         You can write a formal answer and I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `vzeroupper` when mixing VEX and non-VEX vector instructions.  Otherwise you get huge stalls on Intel hardware.

Comment: According to Agner vzeroupper is not necessary with Skylake. In fact on Knights Landing it may be bad to use. See https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-isa-extensions/topic/704023 and http://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=761